# How to tell if video reached end in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to get the video to play in a loop. I want to check if it reached the end of the video so that I can reinstantiate it; How do I make it loop?

```
 VideoStream::VideoStream(Filters* f, char* fileNam):
            filter(f),
            fileName(fileNam){
    TestON = true;
    cap = new VideoCapture(fileNam);
};


void VideoStream::readFrame(){
    if(!cap->isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    cerr<<"cannot open video file";
    if(cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO==1)){
          cap = new VideoCapture(fileName);
    }
    Mat image;
    cap->read(image);
    if(!image.empty())
        imshow("haha", image);
    waitKey(1);
    image.release();
};
```

Comment: You leak memory with your use of `new`. Consider statically allocating a `VideoCapture` instance instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently.. at the end of the video there is an empty frame and you can check for that one this way:

```
if(image.empty()){
    cap = new VideoCapture(fileName);
}else{
    image.copyTo(*_stream);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`VideoCapture::read()` returns a boolean. If `false` it means the camera has been disconnected or there are no more frames in video file.